# siddur(ashkenazi diaspora style) for android/google play store? (that gets weekday mincha 'shalom rav' right)

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, nusach-ashkenaz

I tried two siddurim from the google play store.

I'm looking for one for nusach ashkenaz. (diaspora)..

One test to see if it's right or not wrong(given my requirement) is does it have "shalom rav" for the amidah of weekday mincha.  (it should).

I haven't found one in the two I tried.. (they both had sim shalom for weekday mincha) and one was labelled ashkenaz so I guess was maybe Israeli rather than diaspora.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

If it has Shabbat Davening e.g. Shabbat Mincha(which I know is sim shalom) then all the better (though I understand having shabbat or yom tov davening may be unusual on a phone app!)

Preferably free(no cost).

Comment: Which ones have you tried?

Comment: @WAF siddur ashkenaz by robert r https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=Sidur.Ashkenaz.free&hl=en    and this one, terhillat hashem - dunno if  ashkenaz but didn't have shalom rav for mincha https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=il.avimak.TehillatHashem&hl=en

Comment: @barlop - The Tehillat Hashem is Nusach Chabad.

Comment: @ezra  ah, and btw, is nusach chabad = nusach sfard?

Comment: @barlop - Yes, Nusach Chabad is a version of Nusach Sfard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used [Tfilon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tfilon.tfilon&hl=en) for a few years and really like it. It passes your shalom rav test. It has options for ashkenaz, sepharad, and eidei hamizrach. It is also very flexible - you can add names for holim, select which day(s) you celebrate purim, etc. It also auto calculates the special things like shir shel yom, yaaleh v'yavo, and other day specific things. It even includes the appropriate torah readings (if there are any that day).

There are two places where it falls down (IMO):
1 - It doesn't have hoshanot for sukkot, the time I find myself flipping pages the most often in my siddur and would most like an app.
2 - It is made for Israel. While it passes your shalom rav test, it also includes birkat kohanim for regular shemona esrei, for chol hamoed it uses the Israeli torah readings, and on hol hamoed sukkot it has the Israeli mussaf additions. (In chutz l'aretz, because we have a safek yom we add mentions of two of the korbanot to each day. In EY there is no safek yom so they only mention of the day's korbanot). It also includes morid hatal in ashkenaz (don't know whether you want this or not).

In conclusion I just don't use it on sukkot and skip birkat kohanim when I'm in the states and I'm fine.

Comment: Does it include the _trope_ with the Torah readings?

Comment: @DoubleAA No trope, but it does have nikudot.

Comment: Tfilon passes my weekday mincha shalom rav test -though worth noting that it has a horrible font.. There's a siddur called Tehillat Hashem which uses pictures of siddur pages, and looks nice though tehillat hashem doesn't pass the test.

Answer (score 1):

The best Nusach Asheknaz siddur is AndDaaven
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.saraandshmuel.anddaaven&hl=en

Tfilon (mentioned above) is not proper Nusach Ashkenaz.  For example Psukei D'Zimra has some definite Nusach Sefarad text.  For example Yishtabach is not Nusash Ashkenaz.

Comment: They want $9.99.  The Lite version is only 99 cents.  How does that differ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  AndDaaven is free to install.