# Where can I find an Android siddur with adjustable font size?

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, phone

I've searched for a siddur app for my Android phone and have seen [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44176/472), but so far I haven't found one that will let me increase the font size (including Tfilon, recommended there).  Ideally I want something that will zoom and redo the page layout to adjust, like well-behaved web pages on the phone do, as opposed to something that will involve a lot of horizontal scrolling (like a PDF does).  I'm in the diaspora with Ashkenazi nusach and I'm interested in weekday t'filah and bentching.  I wouldn't be using the phone on Shabbat or Yom Tov anyway so I don't care about coverage there.  I would find it helpful if any special instructions (choreography, when to say variable text, etc) are available in English.  (For the prayers themselves Hebrew is just fine.)

I'm looking for an app rather than a web site because I don't want to be dependent on having service.

Is there an Android siddur that's a little easier on users with less-than-keen vision?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Smart siddur lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.karriapps.smartsiddurlite&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dsmart+siddur+lite+android&pcampaignid=APPU_OuOgVInCIs6OyASCooLwDw) is a free Android siddur app which allows you to adjust font size with finger gestures.

It also allows you to choose your nusach as well as some settings for which prayers to show. Choose the tefila you are interested in and it automatically adjusts the text for rosh chodesh, chol hamoed, etc. that are relevant to the current date and colors them differently so you will notice then. It also tells you relevant zmanim for your location.

Instructions are somewhat sparse, but in English when they appear.

**Edit** Smart Siddur Lite and the full paid version have been combined into one app with in-app purchases. All of the free functionality is still there, but now if you want the full functionality (bris milah, sheva brachos, etc.), you don't download a new app; rather, you make an in-app purchase.

Answer (score 5):

My father and i both use [AndDaaven](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.saraandshmuel.anddaaven&hl=en).

It is nusach Ashkenaz with adjustable font. It has all 3 tfilot, plus bentching. It does not have instructions though.

On my iPad, i use the app "On Your Way -- ובלכתך בדרך", which is [also available for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=oyw.tnc&hl=en). I haven't used the 'Droid version, but on iOS, it has all nuschaot, adjustable size, but still no instructions. But to make up for it, it has tons of other sefarim: Tanach, Talmud, halacha, and much much more.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Tfilon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tfilon.tfilon&hl=en).

You can set font size (out of a list), text automatically adjusts to include special parts of prayer, customizations include different color and Halachic settings and more.

Birkat Hamazon has a Dvar Torah ;)